# Disable cellular radio in android 4.4 +

Tags: android, configuration, airplane-mode

How can I disable/enable cellular network in android? I need to completly disable it for a short time, and since I have android 4.4+ airplane mode is hard to use.

Is it possible to write code disabling only cellular network?

Comment: "airplane mode is hard to use" How is it hard to use?

Answer (score 0):

**Controlling the Airplane Mode**

Check to see if it is enabled or not:

```
boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
      context.getContentResolver(), 
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
```

To toggle it:

```
// toggle airplane mode
Settings.System.putInt(
      context.getContentResolver(),
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

// Post an intent to reload
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And you can use this function:

```
/* Toggle airplane mode for 1 of the 4 allowed types
 * type allowed values: cell, wifi, bluetooth, nfc
 */
private void changeRadioComponentEnabled(Context context, String type, boolean radio_component_enabled, boolean reset){     
        // now toggle airplane mode from on to off, or vice versa
        Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, radio_component_enabled ? 0 : 1);

        // now change system behavior so that only one component is turned off
        // this also affects the future behavior of the system button for toggling air-plane mode. 
        // to reset it in order to maintain the system behavior, set reset to true, otherwise we lazily make sure mobile voice is always on
        Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS, type); 

        // post an intent to reload so the menu button switches to the new state we set
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        intent.putExtra("state", radio_component_enabled ? false : true);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);

        // revert to default system behavior or not
        if (reset){ Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS, "cell,bluetooth,wifi,nfc"); }
        // if reset to default is not chosen, always enable mobile cell at  least
        // but only if NOT changing the mobile connection...
        else if (type.indexOf("cell") == 0) { Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS, "cell");}
}//end method
```

You need the permission `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS`

Read more at:

> http://dustinbreese.blogspot.com/2009/04/andoid-controlling-airplane-mode.html
>
> [How to disable GSM connection in Android  programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7357372/3653989)

**EDIT:** I read that this method is not longer possible to use Android 4.2 and above. But I think that you can read some interesting code that works in:

> [How to turn on/off airplane mode, even on new Android versions (and even with root)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25674655/3653989)
>
> [Toggle airplane mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5533881/3653989)

Comment: I saw that posts before, but it gives `Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE` exception, Do i need root along with permission to use that code?

Comment: @user2654072 as I say in the answer you need the permission `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` you need in your manifest.xml this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />`

Comment: @user2654072 I edit the answer, take a look at the final of the answer.

Comment: @user2654072 you got some advance?

Comment: no luck so far on unrooted phone, i will probably root it and try to make system app, then maybe something will happen. It's crazy that google blocked that from normal developers.

Comment: @user2654072 good luck and of you solve your problem don't forget post the answer ;-)

Comment: Is this resolved ? any way to control airplane mode ?